Django NoReverseMatch Error: How do I generate urls for each Model
I'm facing a NoReverseMatch error in my Django application when trying to generate URLs for product detail pages. The error message indicates that the URL pattern for 'product-detail' with the provided pk and slug is not found. Here are the details of my setup:

NoReverseMatch at /earrings
Reverse for 'product-detail' with arguments '('', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['product/(?P[0-9]+)/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\Z']

Model:
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    description = RichTextField(null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True, max_length=400)
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk, 'slug': self.slug})
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'

View:
class ProductDetailView(DetailView): # this is the product detailView
    model = Product
    template_name = 'tehApp/product_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'products'
    
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(Product, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['Bar'] = Bar.objects.first()
        context['Products'] = Product.objects.all()
        return context
    
    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Product, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])

URL:
urlpatterns = [
    path('product/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/', ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='product-detail'),
]

Template:
{% for product in products %}
<div class="item" data-name="{{ product.name }}" data-price="{{ product.price }}" data-date="{{ product.create_at|date:"Y-m-d\TH:i:s" }}">
        <div class="relative">
            <div class="relative thumbnail">
                {% with images=product.images.all %}
                    {% if images|length > 0 %}
                        <a href="{% url 'product-detail' product.pk product.slug %}">
                            <img width="250px" height="250px" class="" src="{{ images.0.image.url }}" alt="">
                        </a>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if images|length > 1 %}
                        <img width="100%" height="100%" class="hidden" src="{{ images.1.image.url }}" alt="">
                    {% endif %}
                {% endwith %}
                <a href="{% url 'product-detail' product.pk product.slug %}" class="absolute top-0 w-full h-full bg-transparent"></a>
                <div class="hidden quickaddtocart">Add to Cart</div>
            </div>
            <p class="caption"><a href="{% url 'product-detail' product.pk product.slug %}">{{ product.name }}</a></p>
            <div class="caption-price">${{ product.price }}</div>
        </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}

Please raise further questions if necessary,
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

context_object_name = 'products' not product because you're doing, {% for product in products %} your object_list is plural

I excluded the initial page view, because of the character limit in stackoverflow, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Not sure I get what you mean.

The TemplateView for the main page was left excluded, to not cause any confusion that was already present. I have edited the post to be more clarifying, thanks for your insight and please let me know if you could provide more of those insights because I am stumped lol. thx

Are produce.pk and product.slug actually blank or null?

Any reason for explicitly declaring id field? Django automatically does this for you and can be accessed in templates through product.id

If slug is part of your URL, why would you want it blank or null?

@JohnBayko They're all full yeah, it just doesn't seem to be fetching anything.

@16171413 Oh funny thing, I didn't know django automatically did that for me.

I'll assume you determined they have values by putting them in the template (and commenting out the tags that don't work so the page is displayed). At that point I'd explicitly put known pk and slug values in the {% url ... %} tag and see what that produces.

Is that the only path listed in your urls.py? No other path that has product in it?


Setting the context_object_name attribute on a TemplateView doesn't do anything. 2) You're adding Products to  the context but looping over products in the template, Python and hence Django are case sensitive and this wouldn't work.


Solved it, thanks.
It was because of me filling in the super with Product and self. It had to be empty
class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'nasipWeb/product_detail.html'
    model = Product
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['Bar'] = Bar.objects.first()
        return context
    
    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Product, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])

yeah it works now, i appreciate everyone for helping

you provide context['Products'] = Product.objects.all() in views.py.
but you use {% for product in products %} in template.
{% for product in Products %} need.

I think you're right. The view's context_object_name is called products, and that's why {% for product in products %} is looping: product is a dict key (str), so doesn't have .pk and .slug attributes.

in template, if product is class => product.pk get attribute. if dict => get dict value.
It's not only dict data that's possible.
